# Append data from firestore to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm playing with firebase right now, and I want to get display posts from the database.
I've got an array of objects, but I don't know how to get the data into the array.
This is my code:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import db from "@/plugins/firebase";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    get() {
      db.collection("posts")
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.posts = doc.data();
            console.log(this.posts);
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: I think you don't need `forEach` the `snapshot.data()` should be an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out I had to create a new object and then use the spread operator.

This is the working code:

```
    get() {
      db.collection("posts")
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          let items;
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.posts.push({
              ...doc.data()
            });
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Error getting documents", err);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.posts.push(doc.data());
          });
```

All you need is to use push() method so that the data coming from Firebase will get into the array defined above.

Comment: I have tried this, but this.posts is now an observer. When I loop through the posts it does display the correct number of posts, but doesn't display the data, like post title etc.
console.log(this.posts) returns this -> https://imgur.com/a/pNnl0eN

Comment: Maybe with the use of map() operator the data would get transformed into JSON object and then using the subcsribe() method you can display the object data easily.

Comment: I used `JSON.stringify(doc.data())`
If I try using `.map()` it says `snapsot.map()` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

If @shaykoo is getting the idea of your question right then you must use reactive variation of `push()` method like this:

```
.then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc,i)=> {
            this.$set(this.posts, i, doc.data());
          });
```

Comment: Any errors in console? What is `console.log(snapshot.data())` output?